# How to configure Cognos BI Security

Tags: security, authentication, installation, configure, cognos

My cognos installation is on a unix box and currently i have am allowing anonymous access.

But i need to enable authentication now, Ive read about LDAP and AD but i do not fully understand the process or even the differences in setting these up... There has been no specification as to how the security needs to be set up, just that we want a USERNAME / PASSWORD to be able to access cognos connection and reports.

Is there any simple way to create this in cognos connection? or what would be the easiest way to set this up on a unix box where all configuring has to be done via cogstartup.xml as we have to do it manually.

any help would be great :)

Comment: First, I don't know that you can even set up security by directly manipulating the cogstartup.xml file.  That sounds like a disaster waiting to happen, if it's even possible.  Can you not telnet into your unix box, and fire up some sort of X-Windows session, so you can use the configuration utility?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to configure a namespace is by doing so in Cognos Configuration, whose settings get saved in the cogstartup.xml file in configuration — it cannot be done from Cognos Connection.

For a very long time I believed that editing the configuration files was unsupported, and IBM even has technotes that recommend not to do that but instead do it on a computer with a UI, like this one: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21343297

Contrary to Andrew's comment, it's entirely possible to make all the changes to your Cognos just by modifying the cogstartup.xml and coglocale.xml files, and in fact, it's recommended in the IBM documentation here(if you absolutely must): http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEP7J_10.2.1/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.inst_cr_winux.10.2.1.doc/c_cnfg_manualconfigux.html?lang=en

However, I would *highly* recommend that you download the Windows version of Cognos, set it up on a Windows machine(even if it's unsupported like Windows 7), and configure your namespace using the Cognos Configuration utility. You can them Export an unencrypted version of your configuration and place that in the configuration folder of your Linux environment.

The alternative, and probably ideal option, is to install a utility like [Xming](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/) or even [VNC](https://www.realvnc.com/) so you can get a GUI and open Cognos Configuration to visually configure your environment.

I've always been meaning to create a website where people can upload their cogstartup.xml files, configure them using a web GUI and then re-download them, but I haven't gotten around to it.